# Safety tips when carrying a large sum of money

Tags: europe, safety, money, tips-and-tricks

I made the mistake of exchanging a large sum of money before my trip to Europe. I'm not sure what I was thinking because I know it's not the best idea to carry a lot of cash while traveling. What precautions should I take considering my current actions? When I arrive I assume I'll just go straight to the apartment I'm renting and keep my excess cash there. What do you think? Any other safety tips when carrying cash?

Comment: Many countries have limits of the amounts of cash that can be brought into the country, and lower limits at which you have to declare it on arrival. Depending on what you deem "a large sum", you should check into those rules for where you're going!

Comment: $10,000 USD or equivalent is quite typical for both of these amounts but yes it can vary in some countries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First issue to worry about is the flight. Make sure that you keep the money on your body during the flight, there are increasing reports about valuables being stolen by other guests or even flight attendants during long-haul flights from the bags in the overhead lockers.

Another option (if your travel permits) is depositing parts of it in a locker at the train station/airport. Get more when you need it.

Since you are in an apartment, you should be safe leaving items there. If it's a serviced apartment, same things as for hotels noted below apply.

In any hotel, the room safe is the first option. The next option in a good hotel would be to talk to the management and ask them where they would recommend you to "store valuables". They might have another 2-lock safe in the reception area. In a good hotel, you might also be fine with a bag that can be locked, but be aware that something locked will attract thieves, so do not do that in a shady/budget place.

It might be also good if you can find a secret place within your belongings. Soft bags often have a card-board like floor under which items can be hidden. Larger luggage and might have a lining in which items can be placed when cutting open a little corner.

Before I had a credit card, I used to have a leather jacket into which I cut another opening into the lining of the pockets to have access to the space between the lining and the leather. I had another wallet in there with the rest of my money. Like this I had it with me, but it was not visible from the outside.

Answer (score 7):

First rule, don't keep all your money in one place, having that said keep enough money to get you through a day while having extra for emergencies.

Also, if there's a vault use it, otherwise you might wanna keep them somewhere safe, like inside a bag with a code lock, or whatever safe location.

And it is very important to avoid flashing the money around for everyone to see and avoid behave as if you don't have that much money on you in the first place.

Comment: Good tips (+1) but “keep your cash in a safe location” is kind of begging the question…